# Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of integers which converges to l

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of integers which converges to l . prove that there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N,x_n=l$

**My idea:**

since $\{x_n\}\to l$

i.e., there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$  such that for all $n>N,|x_n-l|<\epsilon$

so we can say $x_n=l$ is i am wrong

Comment: You can complete your argument by choosing some proper value for $\epsilon$.

Comment: @drhab...thank you sir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Take $\epsilon = \frac 1 2$ and use the fact that it can't be two distinct integers within an interval having a length smaller than $1$.

Comment: .........$\epsilon = \frac 1 2$ isit implies x_n=l

Comment: ...thank  you sir